# Can't figure out syntax of template nested class in my c++ program

Tags: c++, templates

In my c++ program there is situation that I have a nested template class name outer and it holds a method get() which returns inner class pointer. I need to implement this get() method outside the outer class but i can't figure out the syntax for calling get() method.

suppose :

```
template<typename T>
class outer{
    class inner{
    public:
        T info;
    };
    inner* get();
};
```

However I try replacing inner* get() to auto get() and :

```
template<typename T> auto outer<T>::get(){  return nullptr; // just for example}
```

and its worked but i don't want to use "auto" keyword, So guys please help me to figure out the syntax for implementing get() method outside the outer class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is unrelated to this being a template class. The visibility of `inner` is inside `outer`, and you must therefore provide that scope when you specify it.

```
template<typename T> typename outer<T>::inner* outer<T>::get(){...}
```

Comment: @H.Das If this answers your question, you should accept it.